# How uplaod image to Google Cloud Storage in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, retrofit

I am trying to upload image to google Cloud Storage in my app.
I have a working web-solution, so I can see the all inforamtion of request. 
Here the Raw request of working web-solution

```
    POST /_ah/upload/AMmfu6YbDgVL5B8ZYIBs9VQcZElIKyvHBOG0g-Y3PDsBiVgQLFZNKdzmV-G9gYF3e9SnFUNWCOSP6KDgO5f9bAxkDyNiMeY5EzXW9uWK9ULqXoQostoWySSQkKSzbizJbmjOH1x6mHOkYyWe3kKCn_84qpc1UhUNkw/ALBNUaYAAAAAVwOltAcWY8y-iHPujyHYUBbhmQlwJyi-/ HTTP/1.1
Host: taxi2deal.appspot.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://taxi2deal.appspot.com/
Content-Length: 2718
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------5607231118094935911642858770
Connection: keep-alive

-----------------------------5607231118094935911642858770
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile[]"; filename="ic_uploadphoto.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


IHDR*$�ɨ+tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e<(iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c067 79.157747, 2015/03/30-23:40:42        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 (Macintosh)" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:3B13B96FF1F811E599F4BCD9FCA860E7" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:3B13B970F1F811E599F4BCD9FCA860E7"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:3B13B96DF1F811E599F4BCD9FCA860E7" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:3B13B96EF1F811E599F4BCD9FCA860E7"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>KB3�'IDATx��XkHW7�#h��k��V��i�D��BHZ��H�X�%�Ph�
-----------------------------5607231118094935911642858770--
```

By the way this is my raw response

```
    POST /_ah/upload/AMmfu6b-E_pSrXGteBOj-3LAyVfKs7h24BRJALESmv0km6cecTXCOQCU5r9r8nPszlGtM3zEbyKMcElhP219WqYKYeQCfy6lpOkifBB9HsBiQEOjP10kJyBXyTAQA9P3oWcGjMltZrFgjwAc5vP6g08ssDcj-mvzWw/ALBNUaYAAAAAVwOo2tdzrOgOCiGMq-Gjy7yuyKL063r2/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=69ea02ab-ac17-49a7-9a8b-8be58caf9f61
Content-Length: 66726
Host: 6.taxi2deal.appspot.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/2.3.0

--69ea02ab-ac17-49a7-9a8b-8be58caf9f61
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="call_taxi1459857026278.png"
Content-Type: image/*
Content-Length: 66474
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

This is my Request API using Retrofit

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("/_ah/upload/{key}")
    void imageUpload(@EncodedPath("key") String key,@Part("photo") TypedFile photoFile,Callback<List<ImageUploadResponse>> callback);
```

And this is Request implementation

```
TypedFile photoTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", imageFileName);
                    TypedString name = new TypedString("testName");


                    service.imageUpload(key, photoTypedFile, new Callback<List<ImageUploadResponse>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(List<ImageUploadResponse> imageUploadResponses, Response response) {
                            Log.d("SignUpActivity", "Status Code = " + response.getStatus());
                            Log.d("SignUpActivity", "response = " + new Gson().toJson(response));
                            if (response.getStatus() < 400) {
                                // request successful (status code 200, 201)
                                ImageUploadResponse result = imageUploadResponses.get(0);
                                Log.d("SignUpActivity", "response = " + new Gson().toJson(result));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d("SignUpActivity", "ImagUrl = " + result.imageUrl);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.d("SignUpActivity", error.toString());
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was, that I got empty Body, inspite of 200 Ok response.
After a few hours I noticed, that I need to take special `name` in Body

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="news_file"; filename="news.txt"\r\n
```

Before this, I used random name, it was test, abc, etc. BUT. This name is the name of form, so this should be the name of the form, and not what you want. Hope this help somebody.

In android this should looks like this. I use retrofit.

```
  @Multipart
    @POST("/_ah/upload/{key}")
    void imageUpload(@EncodedPath("key") String key, @Part("news_file") TypedFile photoFile,Callback<List<ImageUploadResponse>> callback);
```

Take a look, that `@Part` is the same as name (e.g `news_file`)